# Cant get simple search work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, simple-form, railscasts

I am a rails newbie. I am trying to implement simple search in my Tweets but **it displays the entire tweets** that are there and not the particular tweet I am searching for. Using SQLITE and Rails 3.2.6

I looked at RailsCasts#37 and bunch of other tutorials but I dont know where I am making a mistake.

My Tweet Model

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :body
    def self.search(search)
        if search
            find(:all, :conditions => ['body LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
        else
            find(:all)
        end
    end

end
```

Controller

```
 @tweets = Tweet.search(params[:search])
```

Form in my Index page

```
<%= simple_form_for tweets_path, :method => 'get', :html => { :class => 'pull-right' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :search, :label => false, :input_html => { :class => 'span3'} %>
<% end %>
```

The Tweet Migration

```
class CreateTweets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tweets do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.references :user

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :tweets, :user_id
  end
end
```

The URL when I search something!

```
http://localhost:3000/tweets?utf8=%E2%9C%93&%2Ftweets%5Bsearch%5D=awesome
```

Looking for help and support! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could be an issue with the `params` hash. You can debug the `params` hash by putting `raise params.to_yaml` in your controller's search action, to see what string is being passed. Also, you can see if it's a problem with the Tweet.search function by testing `Tweet.search("some text")` in the Rails terminal.

Comment: thank you for the comment. I tried with Tweet.search("some text") and the search is working. Cant seem to get an idea on how to use params(:search)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting the name of your param wrong. look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html), 'The name passed to form_for controls the key used in params to access the form’s values', So in your controller you should write something like:

```
@tweets = Tweet.search(params[:tweets][:search])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment! I replaced Tweet.search(params[:search]) with Tweet.search(params[:tweets][:search]), I am getting this error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass Any thoughts?

Comment: The name of the param is probably not tweets. you can output your params and see exactly what is the name of the parameter.

Comment: I am sorry to ask you this! How exactly to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the right way to use simple_form_for, but according to what i see here maybe you should pass in an object: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/

Comment: in order to see the params you can put in your controller temporarily something like `render :text => params.to_yaml`

Comment: thank you! I used the rails form for search. It solved everything. :)